# Are questions about proper design (internal functionality of code) appropriate?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm planning some software, and not sure if my contraption is the proper approach. So I explain it ad ask specific questions not based on opinions. For example:

> I start to develop on Android, and the application is for client DDBB
>   management; depending on the user, the layout may display some fields
>   or not. There are several combinations, so it's not ergonomic to make a
>   different layout for each, and from research I conclude that the best
>   way to implement the layout is a build it up with fragments
>   dynamically.
>
> **Is that a proper approach in terms of**
>
> - Performance and optimization?
> - Workload?
> - Easy to update and/or modify?
>
> Finally, as I said I'm new to Android, so can you tell me which parts
>   of the *Android documentation* I need to learn in order to perform
>   that?

Are those questions inappropriate?

Should I explain more or specify anything?

Specific tags needed?

Comment: That would be primarily opinion-based *and* much too broad, so it wouldn't be appropriate here. But you could try to ask about a *specific* design issue at [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) (if it's too broad it'll also get closed there).

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments: Design (design-pattern, data-structure) fits for Programmers.SE.

However as stated in your question, it's just impossible to answer it like this, and SO/Programmers are not recommendation sites, neither tutorials, or anything like this. They're Question & Answer about a specific problem.

What I think you can ask on Programmer:

- If there is some design pattern that suits to your needs (the layout/fragment thing). However it might be better to elaborate more your requirement.

Performance/optimization/workload: Those points won't be answerable before you have any specific problem with this.

Easy to update/modify: These points don't really mean much, unless you face a true writing problem of your data. Don't think about it though; think about it when you will have the problem and you will have a detailed explanation on how you have done the things and how they should have been done in order to resolve the problem.

> Finally, as I said I'm new to Android, so can you tell me which parts of the Android documentation I need to learn in order to perform that?

This will be definitively off-topic/too-broad everywhere.